# Rebuild indices of Java array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a bidimensional Object array in Java. Some indices aren´t used, because they were skipped during array fill. The array looks like this:

```
Array[0][0]
Array[0][1]
Array[0][2]
Array[1][0]
Array[1][1]
Array[1][2]
Array[3][0]
Array[3][1]
Array[3][2]
```

The *2* is missing, how can I rebuild the indices to make the array "correct"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an element (or set of elements) that aren't populated, you just provide in the missing value(s) using:

```
Array[2] = new Object[3];
```

or are you looking to compress the array ? If the latter, just create a new array

```
Object[] NewArray = new Object[Array.length-1];
```

and iterate through Array, skipping the null value.

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
   if (Array[i] != null) {
      NewArray[j++]=Array[i];
   }
}
```

Unfortunately you can't resize an array once it's created (use an `ArrayList` if you want more dynamic behaviour).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, did you think about:

```
array[2] = array[3];
array[3] = null;
```

Comment: The problem is you still have the 'missing' value - it's now just at the end.

Comment: Then a new array is needed and copying the 'filled' values to the new array. You showed this in your answer already.